# Grep: search and replace full line

Tags: text-processing, grep

The command

```
 grep "foo" myfile.txt
```

prints all matching lines in my file.

Now I want to replace the **full line** with another string. How can I do that?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you're matching a substring of the whole line, you can either use sed's `s` command with a regex to mop up the rest of the line:

```
sed -i 's/^.*foo.*$/another string/' myfile.txt
```

or use the `c` command to replace the matched line in one go:

```
sed -i '/foo/ { c \
another string
}' myfile.txt
```

---

If you don't want to type multiline commands at the prompt, you can put it in a script instead:

```
$ cat foo.sed
/foo/ { c \
another string
}

$ sed -i -f foo.sed myfile.txt
```

Comment: thanks! when i use the second option i get: sed: -e expression #1, char 0: unmatched `{'

Comment: at the end of the first line, you need to type \  and then hit **Return** - it's important that the \  escapes that first newline. Then, make sure the `}'` is on a seperate line from `another string`: the replacement is _everything_ on that second line, including the `}` if you put it there.

Answer (score 3):

You can use *inplace* functionnality of [sed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sed) :

```
sed -i -e 's/foo/bar/' myfile.txt
```

Comment: This will only replace every `foo` with `bar` not the whole line..

Comment: funny enough, I did multiple searches and this question came up as my top result hence for some reason even though the question is to replace the full line I still believe that this answer helps other lost souls out there. I'd update your comment to clarify  and leave the original response.